# What is the best practice to use 'dotnet ef' cli for Service Fabric solution

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-service-fabric

I defined connection string at 'ApplicationManifest.xml' in .sfproj.

However 'dotnet ef' is just for dotnet project, not service fabric solution.

So It cannot read connection string.

Surely, If I define connection string at 'appsettings.json' in each project,
Then can read connection string.

I would like to use the service fabric solution together with the 'dotnet ef' cli tool.

I want to hear what kind of method is the best, empirically.

Comment: Can you use the [EF Core Visual Studio Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell) instead?

Comment: @bricelam Both are in use. Is there any difference in behavior between it and dotnet ef?

Comment: Yes, `Add-Migration` and friends integrate with VS to provide a better experience

Comment: @bricelam Thank you for your advice. Could you give me some concrete examples?

Comment: It opens files after scaffolding them for review and editing; it has tab-completion on parameter arguments; it automatically uses the specified startup project

Comment: @bricelam that tools occurs following error. The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\TestSF\TestSF\TestSF.sfproj\bin\Debug\' because it does not exist.

Comment: @bricelam Have you ever developed using service fabric?

Comment: Nope, but that looks like a but I fixed in EF Core 2.1.0-preivew1-final. See if it works on that version.